# Sparx Enterprise Architect EA 15 - how to sort requirements of an element within a report

Tags: report, enterprise-architect, requirements

While I run the publish to RTF functionality, the requirements in the generated report for an element are printed in an order I would like to influence.

Consider I have two requirements for an element, one requirement of type functional, one of type performance. The report first shows the performance and then the functional. I would prefer having all functional requirements listed before the performance ones.
How can this be influenced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EA offers only 4 options to sort items in a template:

- Name
- Tree Order
- Modified date
- Creation date

You can set these options per template, or when generating a document
[image]

The trick is to getting this done is to use **template fragments**.

If the linked requirement type would be in the list of possible template filters this would have been rather easy.
You could simply create two template fragments, and set their filter to include only functional or technical requirements. Unfortunately the linked requirement type is not included in the available filters.

Alternative is to create two [SQL fragments](https://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.0/model_publishing/custom_sql_fragments.html), one of the functional requirements, and another for the technical requirements.

Then add those to your main template in the order you need them to be.

Comment: Thanks. Any hints where I find documentation so I can develop such an SQL fragment?

Comment: The main place for the documentation is the help. Start here: https://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.0/model_publishing/custom_sql_fragments.html If I find the time all add some details to this answer as well